# How to check form input for length in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How to check for input length in php?

P.S. strlen worked, I had other part of my code wrong, sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: of course strlen works... it must have been something else in the code you don't want to show us that's wrong...

Comment: Could you add your non-working code to the question, please?

Comment: Please define what you mean by "didn't work". The `strlen` function is designed specifically for that purpose. To calculate string lengths..

Comment: I'd also like to point out that in the absence of any input sanitization, someone could easily scrape your entire database by inputting `%%%%` or some similar wildcard.

Comment: Also, sticking $_POST variables straight into sql without escaping certain characters or running any sort of validation is a security risk.

Comment: I would realy like to know how to do that because I am new to this and I dont want my script to have flaws like that, please tell me what I need to exclude and how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, but strlen/mb_strlen does work :)

```
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
$lengthFunction = function_exists('mb_strlen') ? 'mb_strlen' : 'strlen';
if($lengthFunction($name) > 4){
    // $name has > than 4 chars.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

use `strlen()`

```
if(strlen($_POST['whatever']) > 4) {
   echo 'Limit Exceeded';
}
```

If you are using these conditions to throw errors if the user inserts more characters, simply use `maxlength` attribute, will save you a bunch of validation

Comment: This should be updated to use equal or greater than.

Comment: @Yokhannan Done :) and it was already `==`, just can be changed to `<=` or `<=` or `<` or `>` depends on OP